.NET authentication login page
I made Blazor application (.Net 7). Client and server are in different projects. I used ASP.NET Core authentication and IdentityServer4 in project and I scaffold login and register pages in server side  in \Server\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account .
When I run the project in Visual Studio, I can access the pages (login.cshtml and register.cshtml) without any issues. However, after publishing the project, I receive a "Not Found page " message when trying to access the login or registration pages on the client side, and I have not any error messages on client or server side.
I publish project on Azure and client(Deploymentmode: Framework-dependent and Target Runtime: Portable) but the out come is same.
I didn't include the code for my project because I'm unsure which part is related to this issue.

We can't guess what you did, Blazor doesn't use the .cshtml extension and .NET 7 is already out of support. The Long Term Support version is .NET 8.

In any case, when you create a new Blazor project you have the option to use Individual Accounts which scaffolds the appropriate Blazor pages and code

I think we could try to split the app to narrow down the issue. May I know what does "Client and server are in different projects" exactly mean? Do you mean you  create a blazor web assembly app but with asp.net core hosted? Or you create a blazor web assembly standalone app and you create another .net core web api to serve it? By the way, may I know whether the issue would still exist when you disable IS4 in your app? So that we could know "Not Found page" is coming from which scheme. We can't imagine what you have done on your app nor how to reproduce your issue. We need more information.

You need to fallback all your endpoints to the index.html page. In azure using Static Web App we create this file in the root of the project:
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}

staticwebapp.config.json

thanks for response but it already existed in program.cs in server side.     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapControllers();
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});
